# RestFul WCF 4 consuming

Tags: wcf-4

I have a problem with a RestFul WCF 4 service, I've used the visual studio.net template to create one, and when publishing it on the IIS 7 on windows 7, everything ok, I can access the service from the local machine, but when accessing the service from a different PC on the LAN, it says "unable to connect to server" !!!!

I cannot find the problem, please help

Comment: That's it, the IIS does not add an exception for the service's port, I've added my port to the exception list on the Firewall, :)